# Removing a group of words from a character vector

Tags: r

Let's say that I have a character vector of random names. I also have another character vector with a number of car makes and I want to remove any occurrence of a car incident in the original vector.

So given the vectors:

```
dat = c("Tonyhonda","DaveFord","Alextoyota")
car = c("Honda","Ford","Toyota","honda","ford","toyota")
```

I want to end up with something like below:

```
dat = c("Tony","Dave","Alex")
```

How can I remove part of a string in R?

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a close vote.  It's helpful when you vote to close to explain why, especially to a new SO person.  May I ask why this is off topic to the close voter?

Comment: If you want to avoid having both lower and uppercase patterns and use Codoremifa's answer, consider using ignore.case=TRUE in the `gsub` call.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
gsub(x = dat, pattern = paste(car, collapse = "|"), replacement = "")
[1] "Tony" "Dave" "Alex"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just formalizing 42-'s comment above. Rather than using

```
car = c("Honda","Ford","Toyota","honda","ford","toyota")
```

You can just use:

```
carlist = c("Honda","Ford","Toyota")

gsub(x = dat, pattern = paste(car, collapse = "|"), replacement = "", ignore.case = TRUE)
[1] "Tony" "Dave" "Alex"
```

That allows you to only put each word you want to exclude in the list one time.